# Registration & Login

Tags: php, mysql

When attempting to register, it provides the following error

***Something went wrong. Please try again later.***

This hasn't occurred to me before, and I've used this numerous times.

Any idea?

---

**Config.php**

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'REMOVED FOR SECURITY');
define('DB_NAME', 'usersys');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**Login.php**

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Store result
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){
                    // Bind result variables
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                            save the username to the session */
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Register.php**
For some reason, it refused to let me post the code for Register.PHP. so here's a PasteBin. https://pastebin.com/ex2hTUyc

Comment: Nothing in the logs?

Comment: For some reason, PHP manager refused to install on the server. Otherwise i'd look in the logs. That gave the error that it was unsigned

Comment: Please see [mcve], there is a lot of code here, and I am sure not all of it is useful to us. Too much makes it hard to read

Comment: '*When attempting to register, it provides the following error*' - You have shown us the login.

Comment: `$password = trim($_POST['password']);` - is wrong, you shouldn't change the password, simply hash it.

Comment: Remove the login code and include the register code *in* the OP.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 All of it is pretty relevant to be completely honest.

Comment: You use veritable before define. $param_username

Comment: @Script47 It wouldn't let me post the register code. It stated that code wasn't formatted (when it was), so I included a pastebin link.

Comment: Post the generated sql statement. Looks like there an error somehow

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay, I've just seen the issue here, and it's the following code;

```
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

// Set parameters
$param_username = $username;
```

These actually need to be switched the other way around as the `$param_username` is being set after it's used, so making it as thus;

```
// Set parameters
$param_username = $username;

// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);
```

As Script47 says in the comments to this, there is no need to re-declare the valriable for the username as one already exists, so you can make that whole part look like the following;

```
// Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
```

If you did something with `$username`, you could still just change the raw variable, but seeing how it's just "used", there is no need

Seeing the new pastebin updated, line 121 is wrong, you have;

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $password, $email, $toon);
```

You are saying there are 2 strings, but 4 variables, using the following should resolve this;

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $username, $password, $email, $toon);
```

This has 4x "s" rather than 2x in param 2 of the function call

Comment: This has honestly lost me as there's multiple instances of this.

Do you have discord, where we can discuss this further?

Comment: Afraid not - the general idea is you are using your variable before declaring it, you need to make sure that it is set before usage, or just use the main variable itself to have the param `$username`

Comment: I've switched them all over, and it still flashes the error. I'm a tad confused my self

Comment: I have updated the register.php on pastebin. does that look correct?

Comment: No problem, sometimes a second set of eyes is just what we need, please consider accepting if this helped :)

Comment: However, got another issue, will set as the answer if you can fix this one.

Login now produces the error
"The password you entered was not valid."

Comment: @JamesTimms - unfortunately, to ask a secondary question off the back of another question makes it "off-topic" as it detracts from the original purpose, however, you can feel free to add another question (link back to this if relevant), but we cannot answer 2 Q's in the same thread

Comment: I can only post every 90 minutes, I ideally need this asap

Comment: Figured out the issue with the login Sam, don't worry.

Turns out the password on registration wasn't hashing.

Fixed Hashing, and now it works